# Repeat-y is not working for me. The image is not repeating as it should

Tags: css, background-repeat

I have a simple html code below

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="sky"></div>
            <img src="images/arcade-game.png" alt="">
        </div>
        
    </div>
</body>
```

and here is my CSS code

```
.container{
    height:90vh;
    width:90vw;
    background-color: white;
    margin: auto auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    
}

.sky{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(/images/sky.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    animation: movingsky 4s linear infinite;

}
```

I have the animation for the `.sky` to move downwards, however the background isn't repeating as  how I wanted it to be.

Am i missing anything here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`background-size: cover;`  will stretch the image to fill the entire container, therefore no repetitions are visible.   Either remove `background-size` or set it to a fixed size.

Comment: Thank you, I edited according to your steps + a couple of different tweaks and it worked!